# How to edit a BoleanField in Django

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates

please i need your help been stuck like this for days,here is my problem, i have a profile page of a user that contain a BooleanField and a Button if the user would like to subscribe or not, i am wanting to design it this way, in which their will only be a one click button that will show Subscribe and once clicked you you get redirected to the payment page then you choose your plan and make payment,then in the user info it will show a dead btn of Subscribed and underneath would be the code generated for a specific task,just help me share even if its a link to a tutorial to follow as a starting point,here is my code and the picture

### model.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    STATE_CHOICES=(
        (True, u'Yes'),
        (False, u'No'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="patient")
    subscribe = models.BooleanField(default=True, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
```

### html

```
 <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <fieldset class="form-group">
             <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 h4 text-center center">Your Email</legend>
           <legend class=" mb-4 h3 center text-center">{{ user.email }}</legend>
         </fieldset>
         <div class="form-group text-center center">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">{{ user.patient.subscribe }} </button>
         </div>
      </form>
```

[image: instead false and True i want Subscribe and Subscribed thanks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## how do i generate a random numbers or text as plan id

```
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <fieldset class="form-group">
             <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 h4 text-center center">Your Email</legend>
           <legend class=" mb-4 h3 center text-center">{{ user.email }}</legend>
         </fieldset>
         <div class="form-group text-center center">
          {% if not user.patient.subscribe %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
{% else %}
{% if user.patient.subscribe %}
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Subscribed</button>
  <p>Thanks For Subscribing here is your Plan ID  </p>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
         </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: i used UUId instead

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what exactly you want. But it looks like you want to use if statement in your template. Something like this.

```
{% if not user.patient.subscribed %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">{{ user.patient.subscribe }}</button>
{% else %}
    Subscribed!
{% endif %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/

Comment: i am very happy you replied as i am very happy,this is what i want,i dont want it to show True or  False,i want it to show subscribe and when clicked you get redirected to a page to make payment then redirected back to the user profile which then will show Subcribed! and beneath will be a random generated numbers or id that will be use to access some specific page in the website

Comment: you have to generate this numbers in your view and then render it in template.

Comment: thats exactly what i am saying how do i generate random number and text to the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216250/discussion-between-chosenbrain-and-vit-amin).